# Could not load file or assembly Not exact version

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, filenotfoundexception, s#arp-architecture

I'm using MigratorDotNet to do migrations. I give it a string to my Assembly `My_Assembly` which is built on Sharp Arch v2. Sharp Arch v2 is built on Fluent Nhibernate 1.3.0.727.

My project is using **1.3.0.737**

I'm getting the following error when MigratorDotNet calls `Assembly.GetExportedTypes`:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'FluentNHibernate, Version=1.3.0.727, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8aa435e3cb308880' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I'm familiar with BindingRedirects but would prefer to not change source code for MigratorDotNet (it does't pull in external config).

Is there a way I can force the new version and prevent the FileNotfoundException?

P.S. I know there a lot of similar-phrased questions but those are usually resolved by binding redirects, ensuring Copy Local = true, adding assemblies to the GAC, etc. I think this question is more generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to say it, but I think you are going to have to live with binding redirects. I've not found a way to do what you are asking yet myself, but would love to see if there is one.

Comment: Binding redirects would work if the library in question (migratordotnet) loads config files at the time it calls Assembly.Load()..